# Best option for event subscription

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Can you tell me which is the best way to create an event or all the options are good?

```
        // OPTION 1
        buttonAlert.Click += delegate 
        {
            textChange.Text = string.Format("Hello World");
        };

        // OPTION 2
        buttonAlert.Click +=(sender, e) =>
        {
            textChange.Text = string.Format("Hello World");
        };

        // OPTION 3
        buttonAlert.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textChange.Text = string.Format("Hello World");
        };
```

Comment: I would say all options are good. It depends, what style do you like. I like the dot net old style "Event += MethodName".

Comment: Thanks, i think option 1 is my favorite so i will take it.

Comment: You may want a local reference to unsubscribe from events with respect to other EventHandlers.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand. Can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just a matter of preference. In terms of performance are all equivalent.

So, choose based on what you need and prefer.

As a complement of my answer i like to alert that you must unsubscribe a event (-=) after subscrive (+=).

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.140).aspx):

> To prevent your event handler from being invoked when the event is
>   raised, simply unsubscribe from the event. In order to prevent
>   resource leaks, it is important to unsubscribe from events before you
>   dispose of a subscriber object. Until you unsubscribe from an event,
>   the multicast delegate that underlies the event in the publishing
>   object has a reference to the delegate that encapsulates the
>   subscriber's event handler. As long as the publishing object holds
>   that reference, your subscriber object will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Nice! Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you. I just complement my answer with more relevant information.

Comment: Good job, with your "new" information i understood better the solution of @xleon..

Answer (score 2):

I would say that first option is the best when you don´t need the lambda parameters (sender, event). 
Between second and third I would choose second because it´s cleaner (just a matter of preference.

You can also use a method as a delegate, and it´s probably the best if you want to manage memory correctly. When you use a delegate or lambda there is no way to unsubscribe. That means that even if you destroy or leave the activity/fragment, the object will remain in memory and the garbage collector won´t be able to clear it. In the case the user opens and closes this screen many times, you may get an **OutOfMemoryException** eventually. This happens very often in Android. This would be the solution:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    buttonAlert.Click += OnButtonClick;
}

protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();
    buttonAlert.Click -= OnButtonClick;
}

private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textChange.Text = string.Format("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity of your explanation! It was simply and easy to understand.. i will choose this way now.